# AWS S3 ETL tool options

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-glue

Trying to get a handle on what I would use to schedule and run jobs to move data into S3, run scripts on it and move it around s3 afterward.

My requirement is to be able to ingest from API's and also directly from databases. Some formats to ingest will be XML, and others could be flat files. The raw files need to be joined and transformed and turned into a format that graphs could be produced with.

What is AWS glue is like as an ETL tool? My specific question is can you see the finished pipelines showing the data sources and processing parts in a graphical view once they are created?

I have used Azure Data Factory - and it had a graphical UI to view and monitor the pipelines which I found quite useful. Just wondering if AWS glue has a similar thing.

If not - would Nifi on AWS S3 be a good way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Your requirements are not clear. Please explain what you are trying to do and what worked, what you intend to happen. Perhaps something that is ideal for your needs. This way we can find the best that can fit the needs.

Comment: thanks, have edited. Let me know if you need more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for the best GUI, I would recommend NiFi. It is commonly used with S3 and has many connectors out of the box for other data sources. It becomes even more interesting if you want to do things outside of the AWS cloud.

That being said, I would think that Glue will also get the job done.

Running Data Factory when you have a heavy AWS footprint feels like an anti-pattern.

Full Disclosure: Have not worked with Glue/Data Factory and work for Cloudera, the driving force behind NiFi

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently using AWS Glue to extract data from DB into s3, manipulate the data and save it back to Redshift/S3 or send via API to my client. AWS Glue GUI is not that good, you won't see a diagram of your flow and sometimes you will need to use other tools like step functions, airflow to orchestrate your job. Also, most of my jobs I have to use PySpark because AWS Glue methods are too limited. 
Related to monitoring, you can see if there is an error, how many CPU and memory is been consumed by your job, s3 bytes read/written. If you want additional information you need to use logger or print to send it to the logs.